# Can't build C++ project with Android toolchain

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm using Eclipse Luna on Windows 8 and trying to use an existing C++ project with Android. 
I have download the NDK and set the location in `Window->Preferences->NDK`

I'm getting many compile errors in the jni directory which are probably caused because of Unresolved inclusions (like stdio.h, string, jni.h etc).

The current toolchain is Android GCC. The path and symbols include some stuff from the NDK folder after I ran the `ndk-build.cmd` from inside the project's folder, but there probably some includes missing.

I'm not sure what else I need to do in order to build the project.

Comment: Note that Eclipse's proofreading of native code, and the actual build process with the ndk are quite distinct - often setup issues mean the former can fail when the latter is fine.  You will need to figure out which is objecting to what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was and still is with Eclipse itself. The build actually passed but Eclipse still for some reason showed errors which are not really errors and everything is actually working.

This is another proof that Visual Studio is SO much better than Eclipse...